# Check before dataser make changes

Tags: vb.net

I use datagridview and populate it using dataset as follows:

```
 Private GetGeschaftDataSet As New DataSet

Public Function GetDataSet() As DataSet Implements IDAL.GetDataSet
        Dim strcon = New AppSettingsReader().GetValue("ConnectionString", GetType(System.String)).ToString()
        Using con As New SqlConnection(strcon)
            Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM T_Marke", con)
                con.Open()
                ' Create a data adapter in the method and throw it away afterwards
                Using GetProjectsDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                    GetProjectsDataAdapter.Fill(GetGeschaftDataSet, "trial1")
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return GetGeschaftDataSet
    End Function
```

when user ends work with that i save changes to db like this:

```
 Public Sub MakeChangesDataSet() Implements IDAL.MakeChangesDataSet
        If Not GetGeschaftDataSet.HasChanges Then
            MessageBox.Show("No changes to save", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)
        Else
            Dim i As Integer
            Try
                Using MyConnection = New SqlConnection(strcon)
                    Using cmd As New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM T_Marke", MyConnection)
                        MyConnection.Open()
                        ' Create a data adapter in the method and throw it away afterwards
                        Using GetProjectsDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
                            Dim cmdbuilder As New SqlCommandBuilder(GetProjectsDataAdapter)
                            i = GetProjectsDataAdapter.Update(GetGeschaftDataSet, "trial1")
                        End Using
                    End Using
                End Using
                MessageBox.Show("Updated" & i & " marke", "Informacja", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Catch ex As Exception
                MsgBox(ex.Message)
            End Try
        End If
    End Sub
```

However i would like to check whether to not duplicate data, in this case if my table contains columns: Id and Name - i don't want to update if user placed already existing Name. How to achieve that or should i do the check on datagrid level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There some ways to do this.

1. Open a connection and select count all rows with that name and if is zero in the same connection execute the insert.
2. Using a stored procedure which will do all the above.
3. Create a unique index on Name column

I would use the third.